# Magento cache_dir is not writable and throws an error

Tags: caching, magento

I am new to Mangento. Any operation i do like navigation in the admin panel i am getting the following error.

Can someone tell me where can i find the cache_dir directory in a Magento Installation ?
Also it was working perfectly fine until 3 days. what could have made this error ?

http://pastebin.com/jHcD82wv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache folder is by default here:

```
/var/www/html/var/cache
```

or here:

```
/var/www/html/<Magento installation dir>/var/cache
```

By the way, if you're not sure how to find a folder, you can always go to the root directory and do:

```
ls -R | grep -i cache
```

**Update:**

The name of the variable is `cache_dir`. It is taken from: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config/Options.php:

```
$this->_data['cache_dir']   = $this->_data['var_dir'].DS.'cache';
```

Comment: why does the error say the file directory is called "cache_dir"

Comment: try: `sudo chmod +w /var/www/html/var/cache`